# Input.GetKeyUp() is not returning true when appropriate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working on a simple Unity 2D project, and developed a jump system. It was working for a while, but sometime today it just stopped working. It is not completely broken, sometimes the key up is recognised and resets `jumpTimer` and `canJump` as expected, but it seems to happen at random.

```cs
void Jump()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(jump))
    {
        jumpTimer = 0;
        canJump = false;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(jump) && canJump && jumpTimer > 0)
    {
        jumpTimer--;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 0f);
        jumpVector = Vector2.up * jf * 200f;
        rb.AddForce(jumpVector);
    }
    if (grounded && rb.velocity.y <= 0)
    {
        jumpRefresh();
    }
}

void jumpRefresh()
{
    canJump = true;
    jf = jumpForce;
    jumpTimer = timerConstant;
}
```

I've tried changing how things are handled, but trying to rearrange my code just ended up causing issues elsewhere. The issue is specifically with the `GetKeyUp` function. Also, all of this is happening within a `Fixedupdate` function. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Do you use source control? If so, compare charges. If not, start immediately.

Comment: Actually there is no "random". Try to find *which conditions come together* when this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect the input inside the Update() function since the FixedUpdate() may be skipped, and it might miss some input. Do something like this:

```
    bool doJump = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        doJump = Input.GetKeyUp(jump);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(doJump)
        {
            // Jump!
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: I added a n Update() to my code, moved the code that changes the canJump variable, and  it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: that's still not accurate though. It is possible now that `Update` in the next frame already sets your `doJump` back to `false` before `FixedUpdate` is called => exactly the same issue. You will need to rather do it like `if(Input.GetKeyUp(jump)){ doJump = true };` and then within `FixedUpdate` do `if(doJump) { doJump = false; ... }`

Comment: Good point :). /